# Display values of two different arrays in react component

Tags: reactjs

I am building a react app which will display courses and authors, both courses and authors array's i have to display the list of courses and their corresponding authors.
i have used the array map method to map over all courses and display them but i am getting stuck how to display the corresponding authors.
below is my code

```
    import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

function CourseList(props) {
  return (
    <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Author Name</th>
          <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {props.courses.map(course => {
          return (
            <tr key={course.id}>
              <td>
                <button
                  className="btn btn-outline-danger"
                  onClick={() => {
                    props.deleteCourse(course.id);
                    toast.success("Course Deleted");
                  }}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
              </td>
              <td>
                <Link to={"/course/" + course.slug}>{course.title}</Link>
              </td>
              <td>{props.authors.name}</td>
              <td>{course.category}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

CourseList.propTypes = {
  deleteCourse: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  courses: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      authorId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      category: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
  ).isRequired
};

export default CourseList;
```

below is my response Json
[image]

could anyone please help me in displaying the author name in author name cell.

Comment: What is `props.authors.name`? Shouldn't it be `course.authors.name`?

Answer (score 1):

well.. looking at your JSON response.. this could work.

```
<td>{props.authors.find(author => author.id === course.authorId).name}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change  `<td>{props.authors.name}</td>` to  `<td>{course.authors.name}</td>`

don't need to use props for that because you are accessing from array so just access object field of array.

> If `course.authors.name` not found just console your author name and then access that

Comment: in course array there is no  name elements, authors are present in authors array

Comment: @ZahidHussain  share your json response.

Comment: This is my authors data `[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Cory House"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Scott Allen"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Dan Wahlin"
  }
]`

Comment: is something like this possibe `let courses = [...props.courses];
  courses.map(course => {
    course.authorName = "zahid Hussain";
    return course;
  });` but i am using the hardcoded name instead of that i have to get it from authors array

Comment: @ZahidHussain edit your post and share your json response not what you have done